# Laravel 5.8: Internal Server error 500 - Ajax request -

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to send some values to a controller using an ajax request. 
Below the code I am using. After clicking on the related button I get following error.

> check_username' doesn't have a default value..because no value has been sent...500 (internal server error)

What I am doing wrong?

**Route**

```php
Route::post('/checkEmail', 'MemberController@checkEmail')->name('check-email');
```

**Blade**

```js
<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "{{route('check-email')}}",
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        username: jQuery('#username').val(),
        email: jQuery('#email').val()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        // Some Code
    }
});
```

**MemberController**

```php
public function checkEmail(Request $request)
{
    if($request->username) {
        $username = Members::where('member_nickname', $request->username)->count();
        $email = Members::where('member_email', $request->email)->count();

        if ($username > 0 && $email <=0) {
            return response()->json(['success' => 1]);
        }

        if ($username <= 0 && $email <=0) {
            return response()->json(['success' => 2]);
        }

        if ($email > 0 && $username <=0) {
            return response()->json(['success' => 3]);
        }

        if ($email > 0 && $username > 0) {
            return response()->json(['success' => 4]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the logs please.

Comment: Logs says: 'check_username' doesn't have a default value..because no value has been sent...500 (internal server error)

Comment: Since the 500 means internal server error. you need to post the server side code here. instead of client side code. (MemberController check email function)

Comment: What do you have in your controller?

Comment: I posted the related controller function

Comment: I found the issue: a value was missing in the form. Thank you all for your support!